# unable to access variable inside the loop of jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, jsr223

In a thread i am producing a access token and want to use it in http header which is inside a loop, but in the http header i am getting a blank value
My test plan is like

```js
TestPlan
  ThreadGroup
    Http header manager
      token ${token}
    
    http GET request to pull token from server
    Json extractor to extract token from response as ${token}
    
    loop for 100
      http GET request
        JSR223 preprocessor to give search parameters and corresponding values to get request
      
    Listener tree results
```

Comment: can you show your extractor config and some text that you extract from ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your JSON Extractor fails somewhere as given your setup:

1. If you don't set the `token` variable - you will see the header as `${token}` in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

   [image]
2. If you set the `token` variable - the `token` header will have the variable's value:

   [image]

So I would recommend adding a [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) somewhere after `http GET request to pull token from server` and double check that your `token` variable really has the anticipated value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It must be any of your config issue or typo error. Below is sample setup which perfectly works for my project (Note: url & data has been mocked), see if this setup helps to resolve your issue. I am using JMeter 5.0 version :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]